# Download SharePoint folder using Python

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I am using requests library in python to get pages from SharePoint 2010 and it's working fine, now I need to walk through a SharePoint directory and download all files from there to my local machine. Ideally, I would map it as a drive on my computer but this option is not on the table. How would I achieve this using python?